# datacontext of contextmenu not getting set with wpf/caliburn micro

Tags: wpf, contextmenu, caliburn.micro

Im having an issue getting the dataContext set of a contextmenu launched by a button in my "HomeViewModel". The menuitem when clicked cannot find the method call assigned in the xaml.
For reference  here is my xaml for the button and context menu-

homeview.xaml

```
        <Button x:Name="cogButton" Grid.Column ="2" BorderThickness="0" Background="White" Tag="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=cogButton}">
                <Button.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu Name="cm" cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                        <MenuItem Header="Sign Out"                                  
                                  cal:Message.Attach="SignOutClick($dataContext)">
                        </MenuItem>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Button.ContextMenu>
                <Image Source="/Images/TrayCogIcon.png">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger SourceName="cogButton" EventName="Click">
                            <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="CogButtonClick">
                                <cal:Parameter Value="{Binding ElementName=cogButton}" />
                            </cal:ActionMessage>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </Image>
            </Button>
```

homviewmodel.cs-

```
public void SignOutClick(object sender) 
        {
            var s = sender;
        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you get an error when you click the Signout Menu item or cogButton ? Do you have a`CogButtonClick` method in your view model ?

Comment: No errors other than when i click the menuitem! The cogbuttonClick method launches the contextmenu.         public void CogButtonClick(object sender) 
        {

            var addbutton = sender as System.Windows.Controls.Button;
            if (addbutton != null)
            {

                addbutton.ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;

            }
        }